# Generic SOURCES definition in automake depending on other variable

Tags: wildcard, autotools, automake

I'm new to Autotools and I'm trying to add gtest Unit Tests to a project that is using Autotools.

I have a simple directories structure:
`.` - main
`./src` - sources
`./tests` - tests
`./paths` - git submodule with paths

In `tests` directory I have one cpp file per tested class and my `Makefile.am` looks like so:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = serial-tests

AM_CXXFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/src -I$(top_srcdir)/paths  -DUNIT_TEST
AM_LDFLAGS = -pthread
LDADD = -lgtest -lgtest_main

TESTS = test_networkconfig test_dummy   ### depending on content of this variable
check_PROGRAMS = $(TESTS)

test_networkconfig_SOURCES = test_networkconfig.cpp             ### generate this
test_networkconfig_LDADD = $(top_srcdir)/src/networkconfig.o \
                           -lgtest \
                           -lgtest_main

test_networkconfig_CPPFLAGS = $(somelibrary_CFLAGS)

test_dummy_SOURCES = test_dummy.cpp                         ### and this variable
```

I would like to automatically generate:

```
test_networkconfig_SOURCES = test_networkconfig.cpp
test_dummy_SOURCES = test_dummy.cpp
```

Is there a way to create a variable `<some_name>_SOURCES = <some_name>.cpp` for each value that is held by `TESTS` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Automake you can only do this in a limited way.  In particular, for a program `P`, if `P_SOURCES` is not defined, then Automake will compute a default using the program name and the value of `AM_DEFAULT_SOURCE_EXT` (defaults to `.c`).

So in your case:

```
AM_DEFAULT_SOURCE_EXT = .cpp
```

should do the trick.